# How to control Brushless Motor+ESC with BeagleBone?

Tags: brushless-motor, beagle-bone

I can't really find [a real straightforward tutorial](https://www.google.co.id/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=mIg0VZv5K4-HuASa4oCgBg#q=beaglebone%20esc%20brushless%20motor) for that. There are [a lot for Arduino](https://www.google.co.id/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=mIg0VZv5K4-HuASa4oCgBg#q=arduino%20esc%20brushless%20motor) but I only have an original beaglebone, an ESC, and brushless motor with me. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to output a [servo PWM signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_control) with a 20ms period and a pulse width generally between 1 and 2ms depending on your ESC, [Here](http://beagleboard.org/support/BoneScript/analogWrite/) is some information about using the PWM output on a beaglebone, and [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776799-servo-control-from-the-beaglebone-black) is an article describing controlling a servo with a beaglebone, it is the same as an ESC.

Comment: Thank you. I manage to made a 20ms period by putting 50Hz as the frequency (1/0,02=50), a pulse width 1ms to 2ms is 5% to 10% duty cycle right? I can't find any documentation of my ESC (Turnigy Car 18A-SL w/ reverse) about the PWM signal required and found with trial-and-error that my ESC only respon from 4% to 12% duty cycle by the led blink, but only from 8%-10% that the motor actually spin with different speed, below that and it's stop, above then it's at maximum, but I can't make it go backward. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, I normally work with quadrocopter ESCs which only go one direction.

Comment: Did some more research and found this http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uploads/505435513X310686X14.pdf try calabrating the ESC across the full rainge your using it for.

Comment: That's exactly my ESC model! I guess I need to buy the program card..